# How to separate the cardfield input to individual field

Tags: react-native, stripe-payments, strip

I am using Carfield but i want the user fill ever field separately so i can show missing field msg on the the specific field

Answer (score 0):

Separation on CardField of CardForm [is not possible](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-react-native/issues/563#issuecomment-1190530560) at the time being.